# How to link JSF command control to JAVA function?

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I was using Richfaces version 4, I have a command control in XHTML like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{MyBean.doGo}" value="#{msg.Label_Go}" render="tablePanel" execute="@form" id="Go" immediate="true"/>
```

And a bean class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="MyBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {

  public void doGo() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Anyhow, the `doGo()` doesn't work at all, meaning that it doesn't get call. May I know how this could be resolved?

Comment: Did you try to debug it using e.g. `System.out.print("FIRED")` inside the method? It should be called normally...

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183 to exclude all known possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

Watch if you have nested h:form if you have more than one, a4j actions will not work or make sure your a4j:commandButton is within h:form.